# How to build Keras from source

Tags: keras, git-clone

I want to know step by step process of building keras from source. On internet everybody says clone keras from [github](https://github.com/keras-team/keras) and then **CD** into it and run **python setup.py install** but there is no setup.py file there. Also there is something called as bazel installer in keras which I am not understanding. Can you please give me the step by step process for this. And also is there are documented guide for it? because I didn't found anything like that, if you know it please mention it in answer.

[Keras github home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tPyC.png)

I did tried running setup.py file in keras/tools directory but that also is not working.